# Dropzone remove all files

Tags: angularjs, dropzone.js

---Dropzone JS---
How can I remove all files with single API call?

Let say,
I've uploaded 4 images; on popup close/cancel event I triggered `removeAllFiles(true)`, that will remove files from Dropzone area, but calling 4 API calls.

How do I get an array of files & remove at once?

```
_.extend(vm.dzOptions, {
    "init"           : function () {
        let _this = this;

        // Setup the observer for the button.
        document.querySelector("button.attach-cancel-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            // If you want to cancel uploads as well, you
            // could also call _this.removeAllFiles(true);
            _this.removeAllFiles(true);
        });
    },
    "sendingmultiple": function (files, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append("destination", dzOptionsData.destination);
        formData.append("attachmentCount", files.length);
    },
    "removedfile"    : function (file) {
        if (file.status !== "canceled") {
            $http.post("/delete-file", {paths: file.absolutePath}).then(
                (res) => {
                    res = res.data;
                    if (res.code == "OK") {
                        file.previewElement.remove();
                        Notification.success({"message": res.message, replaceMessage: true});
                    }
                    else {
                        Notification.error({"message": res.message, replaceMessage: true});
                    }
                },
                (err) => {
                    Notification.error({"message": err.message, replaceMessage: true});
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

There should be a feature called `removemultiple` like other multiple options.

Thanks.

Comment: `removeAllFiles(true)` should already remove all the files in dropzone, consider adding extra information, like the complete dropzone configuration you are using and dropzone version.

Comment: v5.5.0, `removeAllFiles(true)` should already remove all the files in dropzone.
I'm using API to upload/remove files. So `removeAllFiles(true)` calling `removeFile` for each file uploaded.

Comment: I'm having API, that removes all files at once, then why should I call for multiple API call.

Comment: Now I am not sure what is exactly that are you asking, consider adding some example to better explain your goal.

Comment: I think I see now, when you say remove the files you mean to remove the files also from the server. I don't think there is a way using dropzone events since the `removedfile` event will trigger for every file, a simple way I can think is to do it from inside the listener of the button, you can manually get an array with the files using `_this.files` then make a single ajax call to the server from there.